# error "sh: : command not found sh: : command not found" number 127

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I am trying to make an AppleScript with the commands below and when I run it has an error with the do shell script command. I tried running this in terminal and it works perfectly fine so I think there's a problem with the AppleScript telling the shell script to execute. Does anybody have a solution? Also is it necessary to have an `end run` at the end of my script?

```
do shell script "screencapture -R123,456,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
                 xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
                 sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
```

Edit: Also how would you make the output of the shell script a var?

Edit 2: Running `do shell script "screencapture -R123,456,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp"` works just fine so I think it may have to do with the tmpdir

Edit 3: I ran it again and it worked just fine somehow so if anyone knows how to make the output a var that would be great thanks!

Comment: `$TMPDIR` is not defined, so it is probably complaining about that.  The `do shell script` command does not need an `end run`.

Comment: CrazeDave, Works just fine on my system.

Comment: @red_menace, `TMPDIR` is defined, just run `do shell script "echo $TMPDIR"` and on my system it returns e.g. `/var/folders/71/rhgmzdz532d6tqqfx372xdk00000gn/T/`

Comment: BTW That's an interesting way to get the hexadecimal color notation of a single pixel at the given coordinates.

Comment: @user3439894 what do I do with the /var/folders/71/rhgmzdz532d6tqqfx372xdk00000gn/T/ after I get it?

Comment: CrazeDave, What do you mean by "what do I do with the ... after I get it?", it's your _code_. As I said in my answer  "I copied and pasted your **AppleScript** _code_ and ran it in **Script Editor**. It ran without error and I see nothing wrong with the _code_."   `TMPDIR` is going to be different on each system and you do not need to do anything with it as `$TMPDIR` expands `TMPDIR` and that is where your `test.bmp` _file_ is being written to.

Comment: @user3439894 Yea I was just wondering what the purpose of ```do shell script "echo $TMPDIR"``` was

Comment: CrazeDave, That was in a comment addressed to red_menace because he said "`$TMPDIR` is not defined" which isn't true and why I said "`TMPDIR` is defined, just run `do shell script "echo $TMPDIR"` ... I do not know why he'd make a statement like that to begin with as he's very knowledgable. In other words, he was suggesting that was you're issue and I was refuting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted your **AppleScript** *code* and ran it in **Script Editor**. It ran without error and I see nothing wrong with the *code*.

To make what is returned from the `do shell script` *command* into a *variable* use, e.g.:

```
set hexColor to do shell script "screencapture -R123,456,1,1 -t bmp $TMPDIR/test.bmp && 
    xxd -p -l 3 -s 54 $TMPDIR/test.bmp | 
    sed 's/\\(..\\)\\(..\\)\\(..\\)/\\3\\2\\1/'"
```

You do not need an `end run` unless you have an `on run`.